# How to ensure exception safety in c++?

Tags: c++

In a highly secure system, how to ensure exception safety?

Comment: Do you mean ensuring that all exceptions are caught?

Comment: I am not very sure about exception safety, so if you can , please answer it too.

Comment: I just wanted clarification on you question, it is not very descriptive, please use something like examples to further clarify it.

Comment: check this user705414214324535 [Writing “Exception Safe” C++](http://www.octopull.demon.co.uk/c++/JACC99/index.htm).

Comment: Do you want to verify whether a piece of code is exception safe, or do you want to write exception safe code? At any rate, analysis of exception safety is hard.

Answer (score 2):

### A very general answer to a very general question...

Ensure the software engineers writing it have read and understood [Herb Sutter's Exceptional C++](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0201615622/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&tag=johnsydotorg-21&linkCode=as2&camp=1634&creative=19450&creativeASIN=0201615622).

[image: Herb Sutter's Exceptional C++]